# how to select a row a matching a text with protractorjs

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

we are using protractorjs and node for our test automation. as we have two web application one with customer facing which is ReactJS application which has very reactive elements on those we are using this framework. In the agent facing application we have a page which has normal html table. i was trying to match the text of my choice and double click on it to open a model box. i was able to find the number of rows on the table, but could not go to the exact row of my choice. could any one help me on this with any protractorjs functions.

in this case i need to navigate to 'ETHBTC' and double-click on that to open its details in new pop-up model box.

Page Element

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Instrument ID</th>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>BTCUSD</td>
            <td>Running</td>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>ETHBTC</td>
            <td>Running</td>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>ETHGBP</td>
            <td>Running</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

screen picture

[image]

code:
after getting row count do not know how to traverse to required row and select that. i know we have to use for loop to traverse, but dono how to match the the expected one.

```
const service_table = element(by.css('.table'))
let table_rows = service_table.element.all(by.tagName('tbody')).all(by.tagName('tr'))
let rows_count = table_rows.count()
```

**UPDATED**

here is my full mrthod for double clicking activity on the table row

```
  async open_exchange_service(data) {
    await browser.sleep(1000)
    const service_table = await element(by.css('.table'));
    const table_row = await service_table.element(by.cssContainingText('tbody tr td', data));
    try {
      console.log('i am in tryyyyyyyy loooppppp')
      await browser.actions().click(table_row).perform().then(() => browser.actions().click(table_row).perform());
      // await browser.actions().
      //   mouseMove(table_row).
      //   doubleClick().
      //   perform();
      // await browser.actions().
      //   mouseMove(table_row).
      //   doubleClick().
      //   perform();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('i am in catchhhhhh looppppp')
      const service_table = await element(by.css('.table'));
      const table_row = await service_table.element(by.cssContainingText('tbody tr td', data));
      await browser.actions().click(table_row).perform().then(() => browser.actions().click(table_row).perform());
      // await browser.actions().
      //   mouseMove(table_row).
      //   doubleClick().
      //   perform();
      // await browser.actions().
      //   mouseMove(table_row).
      //   doubleClick().
      //   perform();
    }
  }

  async open_exchange_instrument(data) {
    await browser.sleep(1000)
    const service_table = await element(by.css('.table'));
    const table_row = await service_table.element(by.cssContainingText('tbody tr td', data));
    try {
      console.log('i am in tryyyyyyyy loooppppp')
      await browser.actions().click(table_row).perform().then(() => browser.actions().click(table_row).perform());
      // await browser.actions().doubleClick(table_row).perform();
      // await browser.actions().doubleClick(table_row).perform();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('i am in catchhhhhh looppppp')
      await browser.sleep(500)
      const service_table = await element(by.css('.table'));
      const table_row = await service_table.element(by.cssContainingText('tbody tr td', data));
      await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', table_row);
      await browser.actions().click(table_row).perform().then(() => browser.actions().click(table_row).perform());
      // await browser.actions().doubleClick(table_row).perform();
      // await browser.actions().doubleClick(table_row).perform();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cssContainingText` to identify a specific row by text:

```
const service_table = $('.table'));
const table_row = service_table.element(by.cssContainingText('tbody tr td', 'ETHBTC'));
browser.actions().doubleClick(table_row).perform();
```

Comment: I tried the same way, i can see it is finding that row, but actually it is not doing the double click action. its not opened with the expected model box. any help. i tried with traditional way of approach too, by counting total rows and with for loop matching the element text and then double click action.  Now my problem is either way the <code> "await browser.actions().doubleClick(table_row).perform();" <code> is not doing its double click action.

Comment: Ahhh, you're using async/await.  Check out this bug: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4578
It seems like `await` doesn't play nice with `browser.action()`.  You can await a singe action, but you can't chain multiple together (and I suspect `doubleClick` is just two clicks chained together).  We've run into this and had good luck with the workaround on that bug, just `perform()` each individual action.  You might try `await browser.actions.click(table_row).perform().then(() => browser.actions.click(table_row).perform());`
(super ugly, I know).

Comment: "@nathaniel C" i tried your suggestion. but no luck. i see a error `TypeError: browser.actions.click is not a function`. Can you please help more on this?

Comment: Oh, woops, I forgot the parentheses on browser.actions(), twice in fact.

Comment: "@nathaniel C" i have tried that too. but still no luck. I have updated my full method in the question. can you please help me on where it is a problem. I still get a error on the next step. Because the double click activity is not happening on the "open_exchange_service" method, all the other steps in my test are failing.

Comment: Gosh, I'm not sure.  You could try using a regular `await table_row.click(); await table_row.click();` since `browser.actions()` doesn't seem to be buying anything.  You could try hovering the mouse over the element before double clicking, just in case that's somehow important to make it listen for the click.  You might want to post the code that calls the `open_exchange` methods, just in case something is wrong there (you're awaiting those calls, right?).  You could try `console.log(await table_row.isDisplayed())` just to make sure it's truly visible.